# Connect Flash game score to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, flash

So I've created a flash quiz which shows the number of question they get correct at the end of the quiz. How do I save this score in a MySQL database?

Comment: @hek2mgl 
I did not use MySQL database, but instead used phpMyAdmin. The problem is that we have little knowledge on Flash and Php codings and I have tried to use codes found on Stackoverflow but failed.
I really do not know how to start connect the two.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is a web frontend to manage MySQL databases. It is written in PHP. Therefore the name is Php - My (sql) - admin.

Comment: A quick way: create a form php script that can insert the scores in to your database. No flash involved for this part alone. There are plenty of examples for this part. Once that part works, write your flash quiz to call that php script, passing along the score data. Flash calls php, which inserts the score into the database.

Comment: We have created a form in the database with ID and score. Now we have a problem in calling the php script from flash. This is what I did:

Comment: playerx=new LoadVars();
_root.submit.onRelease=submitScore;
function submitScore():Void{
 response.text="clicked\n";
 
 playerxscore=score_txt.text;
 playerx.sendAndLoad("ScoreTable.php",playerx,"POST");
}
playerx.onLoad = onLoadCallBack;
functiononLoadCallBack(success)
{
 response.text+="onLoadProcessed\n";
 
 if(success){
  response.text+="Success\n";
  response.text+=this.lVar1+"\n";
  response.text+=this.lVar2;
 }else{
  response.text+="Loading Error!";
 }
}

Comment: and we tried to use this codes for php:

<?
$var1 = $_POST['score'];

echo "&lVar1=$var1returned&";
?>

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the code in your comments seems to look okay at a glance, although are you missing a period?

Second line in your submitScore() method:

```
playerxscore = score_txt.text;
```

should be:

```
playerx.score = score_txt.text;
```

?